# Set Width of XRPictureBox at Runtime

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I am creating devexpress xtrareport's xrpicturebox as below.

```
        if (dtPath.Rows.Count <= 0) return;

        var panelResimler = new XRPanel {Width = 800};

        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < dtPath.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            XRPictureBox xrPictureBox1 = new XRPictureBox
            {

                ImageUrl = dtPath.Rows[i]["DokumanYolu"].ToString(),
                Sizing = ImageSizeMode.AutoSize,
                Dpi = 100F,
                LocationFloat = new DevExpress.Utils.PointFloat(x, y),
                Name = "xrPictureBox1",
            };

            //if (xrPictureBox1.Width > 800)
            //{
            //    xrPictureBox1.Width = 800;
            //}

            if (xrPictureBox1.Right > 800)
            {
                xrPictureBox1.Left = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                xrPictureBox1.Top = 0;
            }

            if (xrPictureBox1.Bottom > y) y = xrPictureBox1.Bottom;
            x = xrPictureBox1.Right;

            panelResimler.Controls.Add(xrPictureBox1);
        }

        Detail2.Controls.Add(panelResimler);
```

The problem is, when I use panel as here image part is not getting visible while size doesnt fit to the report. BTW the comment out part does not help here.

Othervise if I wont use panel that time image streching to severap pages.

are there any solution for limiting image width by page width?

This is what I desire
[image: This is what I desire]

This is without panel
[image: This is without panel]

Thans in advance...

Comment: from your description it is not clear what are you doing: do you want to show many pictures bounded to the datasource? or do you want to add many pictures for a single data row (for a single band)?

Comment: @k0st1x Sorry, I ve just added images what I desire. 

I want to tile images inside report dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

ImageSizeMode.AutoSize mode will not set specific size for control - it will be corrected on printing / document generation process. so you should not look at the control size (Right and Bottom properties), you can change the picture size as a page size divided to count of pictures in line (if i correctly understand your scenario) and set the PictureBox Sizing mode to Zoom image or Squeeze (or smth similar).